# Php-fpm & Nginx in docker conatainer performance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, nginx

we are working on an online Exam system which will have high traffic at the same time, the system developed using laravel and MySQL as database.
our server has 40 core and 64 GB RAM memory.
I installed Nginx in a docker container
PHP in another container
Mysql in another container,
also we tested the system with the classic way, where all services working in the same server directly without docker.
but the problem is the system can not handle more than 600 Users at the same time.
we tried with Nginx performance tunes and nothings works, and also with php-fpm.
I don't know why is that happening, we tried with all architecture that can help but nothings work, every PHP-fpm process using 27% of CPU .
and when I am using

> ApacheBench

in order to send requests to the server and then trying to load the home page from my browser it taking a long time to respond to the page and many times return time-out.
I am using  `Nginx:stable-alpine` as Nginx docker image.

```
php:7.4-fpm-alpine
```

as PHP image.
I did not change any of the default configs for PHP or Nginx.
so what is the best configuration for PHP and Nginx which I have to apply in order to have the best performance?

htop result before send requests
[image]

htop after send request using

> sudo ab  -n 5000 -c 600 https://demo.qsinav.com/

[image]

Comment: For each server involved, Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thank you for your help , I  posted in pastebin.com and include all information that you asked for this is the link https://pastebin.com/Jsr7YpX0

Comment: Any SSD or NVME devices on this server?  Single server supporting all your activities?  From OS command prompt, could you post TEXT results of either htop or top?  New request, TEXT results of MySQLTuner.pl (perl script) for additional info including by Engine, Table Count and Data size and much more detailed information.  What is your country/time zone?  We are in UTC -6hrs USA Central Time Zone.

Comment: can we havve chat ?

Comment: Your version 8.0.0-dmr was released 2016-09-12 as Development Milestone Release.  DMR are usually not used for any production systems.  Recommendation, 8.0.21 with General Availability Date of 2020-07-13 would be a good candidate with 3 months of other people finding and reporting any difficulties with the version.

Comment: Yes, Skype Chat my id is wlhauck@aol.com and available at this time.

Comment: I already sent friend request to u ,please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 9 to reduce threads_created RPhr of 78 
net_buffer_length=32K  # from 16K to reduce # packets per hour 
query_cache_size=0  # from 1M to conserve RAM because the QCtype of OFF
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF to allow awareness and proactively correct
long_query_time=1  # from 10 seconds - if overwhelmed with entries, raise the seconds by 1 
innodb_write_io_threads=64  # from 4 to expedite writing to tables on storage devices
```

There are many more opportunities to improve configuration.  View profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning, specifically findfragtables.sql is helpful with reminding you to OPTIMIZE heavily used tables periodically.